# Elastic Search: Mapper for [_all] conflicts with existing mapping in other types

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to create edge ngram index and map the document. I am using python elasticsearch api to do this.

This is my index body.

```
body = {
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "ngram_filter": {
                        "type": "edge_ngram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 20
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "ngram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "ngram_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my mapping of a document.

```
user_mapping = {
        "_all": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        'properties': {
            'id': {
                'type': 'long',
                'include_in_all': False
            },
            'uuid': {
                'type': 'string',
                'include_in_all': False
            },
            'email': {
                'type': 'string',
                'include_in_all': True,
                "term_vector": "yes"
            },
            'screen_name': {
                'type': 'string',
                "include_in_all": True,
                "term_vector": "yes"
            },
            'display_name': {
                'type': 'string',
                "include_in_all": True,
                "term_vector": "yes"
            },
            'first_name': {
                'type': 'string',
                'include_in_all': True,
                'term_vector': 'yes'
            },
            'last_name': {
                'type': 'string',
                "include_in_all": True,
                "term_vector": "yes"
            },
            'lat': {
                'type': 'long',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'lon': {
                'type': 'long',
                "include_in_all": False
            },
            'public_status': {
                'type': 'string',
                "include_in_all": True,
                "term_vector": "yes"
            },
            'score': {
                'type': 'long',
                'include_in_all': False
            },
            'groups': {
                'type': 'string',
                'include_in_all': False
            },
            'created_at': {
                'type': 'date',
                'include_in_all': False
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try to map this, I am getting this exception. Not sure what is wrong with my map.

{u'status': 400, u'error': {u'root_cause': [{u'reason': u'Mapper for [_all] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [_all] has different [analyzer], mapper [_all] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [_all] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]', u'type': u'illegal_argument_exception'}], u'type': u'illegal_argument_exception', u'reason': u'Mapper for [_all] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [_all] has different [analyzer], mapper [_all] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_analyzer] across all types., mapper [_all] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [search_quote_analyzer] across all types.]'}}

Comment: I think you are posting the mapping into _all instead of the type of document you want to update.
Have you tried posting your mapping into a template or directly into one of your index ?

Comment: should i remove the _all tag, and set these properties inside each field.  "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer", "search_analyzer": "standard"